# Infinite grid store is not loaded

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

The view looks like so:

```
Ext.define('GridGeneral.view.GridGeneralPanel',{
    extend:'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias:'widget.GridGeneralPanel', 
    initComponent:function(){
        var me = this;
        Ext.applyIf(me,{
            layout:'fit',
            border:false,
            columnLines:true,
            loadMask:true,
            viewConfig:{},
            columns:[]            
        });
        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

The store is following:

```
Ext.define('GridGeneral.store.GridGeneralStore',{
    extend:'Ext.data.BufferedStore',
    model:'GridGeneral.model.GridGeneralModel',
    constructor:function(cfg){
        var me = this;
        cfg = cfg || {};
        me.callParent([
            Ext.apply({
                autoLoad:true,
                leadingBufferZone:300,
                pageSize:100, 
                proxy:{
                    type:'ajax',
                    url:'/modules/grid/data/',        
                    extraParams:{
                        format:'json'
                    },
                    reader:{
                        rootProperty:'data',
                        totalProperty:'total'
                    }
                 }
           },cfg)
       ])
    }
});
```

This is the controller:

```
Ext.define('GridGeneral.controller.GridGeneralController',{
    extend:'Ext.app.Controller',
    models:['GridGeneralModel'],
    stores:['GridGeneralStore'],
    views:['GridGeneralPanel'],
    refs:[{
        ref:'gridPanel',
        selector:'GridGeneralPanel'
    }],
    init:function(){
        Ext.getStore('GridGeneralStore').addListener('metachange',
                                     this.metaChanged, this);
    },
    metaChanged:function(store, meta){
        this.getGridPanel().reconfigure(store, meta.columns);
    }
});
```

And, finally, this is what the server returns to the client:

```
{"msg":"","total":"160","data":[{"stream_name":[...],"stream_size":[0],"_version_":"123456",
"id":"abcd-efgh-hijk-lmno"},.....],"metaData":{...}]}
```

Almost everything seems ok - grid is rendered, columns are rendered and so on. But the only problem I see is that store not loaded to the view - I see no grid rows at all. So, what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

So, nobody in the world can create mvc with dynamic infinite grid?

**EDIT**

It is obviously some bug. I moved to extjs 6.0 and now everything works fine.

Comment: Did you inspect the grid in Firebug or similar? Are the view rows there? Maybe the grid view has zero height? Attach a `viewready` event and, in the handler, check if the view has nodes at all.

Comment: I've just inspected it in Firebug. Its height is 100% (spans the whole screen), besides I checked the dom structure and see that there are no rows at all inside x-grid-item-container.

Comment: However, if I switch to `Ext.data.Store` and change `reader` config a little bit (rootProperty->root etc), then I see store is loaded.

Comment: So, I guess I miss some properties, some configuration which I do not know. Although, I follow dot by dot standard examples.

Comment: If someone could provide the simplest in the world working mvc-example where an infinite grid is dynamic (uses metaData and reconfigure), that would be a great help and worth +100500 of reputation.